# automatic extraction of contour lines from a scanned paper map

Tags: raster, fme-form, contour, trace

I'm currently trying to detect contour lines from a georeferenced raster image, which looks like this:

[image]

With the help of FME I could extract the lines very good. But they are divided at every section. For clarification I coloured some of them:

[image]

Now my question: Does anyone know a workaround for this? Or is there already a tracing algorithm, which combines the separated lines to individual lines.

Comment: Maybe GRASS `v.net` with tool `connect` and a threshold to connect gaps : https://grass.osgeo.org/grass82/manuals/v.net.html . It might work in some cases with a small gap, but can create aberrations if the threshold is too big, by connecting the wrong line.

Comment: Do your vector contours have attributes like elevation?

Comment: I'd probably try the Snapper transformer. If you can add elevation as an attribute, as @Mapperz suggested, then use that as a Group-By attribute to ensure contours of different elevation don't snap together.

Comment: Unfortunately my detected lines have no elevation information.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the case, I would use the Snapper / Line extender with then a line combiner based on the featureType

[image]

The LineCombiner would be used to combine the same adjacent segments into "bigger" lines.

[image]

***(Above sample extracted from FME Desktop LineCombiner Help)***

Note: if you choose to use the extender, you may have to intersect the lines then remove the small bits of lines by using a length calculator and remove the small size lines with a tester.